# Issue while sorting a map

Tags: java

I have a map

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(21,"A");
map.put(9,"B");
map.put(23,"C");
map.put(25,"D");
```

I sorted it like this

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
@Override
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o1%10 - o2%10;
  }
});
Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
for(Integer key: list){
  sortedMap.put(key, map.get(key));
}
System.out.println(sortedMap);
```

Gives output `{21=A, 23=C, 25=D, 9=B}`

Even tried like this

```
Collections.sort(list);
Set set = map.entrySet();
Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
for (Iterator it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Still same result

**Why 9 is coming at last it must the first entry .**

Comment: because 9 is biggest in ones place of all numbers !!! you are comparing last digit of all numbers...

Comment: Because you asked for it ! By explicitely stating `% 10`, you only keep the last digit of your numbers for the sort. :)

Comment: really this is stupidity how can I ignore that btw thanks for the help

Comment: The original map is already sorted. You only create a new *ordered* map that keeps the insertion order. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function is comparing only the last digit of each number:

```
@Override
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o1 % 10 - o2 % 10; // a number modulo 10 yields it last digit, e.g. 25 % 10 = 5
  }
});
```

You are comparing the last digits of (21, 9, 23, 24) which are (1, 9, 3, 4). In this way, 9 is the biggest number and hence the last one in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
 List<Integer> list = new LinkedList(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o1 - o2;
            }
        });
```

Is there any specific reason to use - `%` ? Which is changing the order of result.

This is the output with above

`{9=B, 21=A, 23=C, 25=D}`